# Como fazer um servidor de Arquivos e de Homologação

Tags: servidor

Boa tarde galera,

Sou desenvolvedor Web, e gostaria de fazer/aprender um servidor Web.

No caso minha duvida seria pelo que eu devo pesquisar.

**Exemplo**: se eu alugar um servidor Cloud(me recomende empresa) com Linux, vou conseguir configurar uma pasta para documentos em um endereço de ip para mapear uma unidade de rede no PC/MAC, como fazer?

Como fazer o backup desses arquivos?

Sobre um servidor de homologação quais seria os passos para configurar um Servidor PHP/Node, com endereco de exemplo: http://cliente.nomedaminhaempresa.com.br

Obrigado